# Generate ports in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

Is there a way to generate port declarations in VHDL? I would like to do something similar to #IFDEF for debug signals out to pins for an oscope. That way I can quickly enable or disable debug logic. For example:

```
entity my_entity is
port (  

    debug_label: if debug_on = 1 generate
    debug1: out;
    end debug_label;

    ....

    );
end component;
```

When I try something like this is doesn't work. Is there any way to make it work? Or an alternative way to do something similar?

Comment: If you're adventurous you could use [m4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M4_%28computer_language%29) to add macros to your code. It would require some care, though, to ensure that your tools only see the post-processed source. This is the type of problem m4 is designed to solve.

Comment: To save wiring through the hierarchy, have you considered using an impure function instead of ports to communicate the debug information?  See https://github.com/chiggs/hidden_wires for a synthesisable example in SystemVerilog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ports can't be conditional, but the length of for example a
`std_logic_vector` can be configurable through a generic, and the length may
even be 0, resulting in null range.  An entity showing this is:

```
entity mdl is
  generic(
    DEBUG_LEN : natural := 0);
  port(
    ...
    debug_o : out std_logic_vector(DEBUG_LEN - 1 downto 0));
end entity;
```

You should run a test synthesis to see how the your selected synthesis tool
handles null range when assigning to pins.